# Running Processing.js on Meteorjs 1.4

Tags: meteor, processing.js, c9.io

Need help to run processingjs on Meteorjs for my project. I have added the package from bgrayburn and still have difficulty in being able to run processing file.
I use cloud9 as my platform to run and flow router. In the picture is the file organization.

**file organization:**

[image]

Here's my code on my page1 template:

```
<template name="page1">
<body>
    <div>
      <h1>HELLOO to Page1!</h1>
          {{> processingSketch}}
     </div>
</body>
</template>

<template name= "processingSketch">
  <div style="border-style:dotted;">
  <canvas style="border-style:solid;" data-processing-sources="mysketch.pde"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

On the browser I got like below:

**view in browser:**

[image]

You can see that the html works fine, but it does not run the sketch.pde file. What did I miss? I really appreciate your answers. If possible please include screenshots.

Comment: Let try `/mysketch.pde` instead of `mysketch.pde`

Comment: You will need to activate your drawing from javascript, due to the way that Meteor interprets the HTML, which is preventing your script from running. Read the getting started docs in processingjs to work out how

Comment: @Mikkel, I wish a more specific explanations, especially if you have solved the same issues. However, the idea of reading "getting started docs in processingjs" works well. I still appreciate your help!